# Android - Remove a row from horizontal scrollable listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, horizontalscrollview

I have a list view with two text view and a delete button on the right corner (hidden), each list item is scrollable and delete button appears when I scroll to the left. I was able to get the position in the list onclick of delete button but I am unable to remove that list row.

Layout looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTeamInvitesListItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:onClick="onClickTeamInvitesListText"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.headsup.customviews.TextViewPlus
                    android:id="@+id/textViewListNameTeamInvites"
                    style="@style/text_view_list_item_style"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:focusable="false" >
                </com.headsup.customviews.TextViewPlus>

                <com.headsup.customviews.TextViewPlus
                    android:id="@+id/textViewListEmailTeamInvites"
                    style="@style/text_view_list_item_style"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:focusable="false" >
                </com.headsup.customviews.TextViewPlus>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonListViewTeamInvite"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/teams_invites_listview_button_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFF0000"
                android:onClick="onClickTeamInvitesListButton"
                android:text="@string/delete" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I have to remove the list row when I click on delete button so I have "onClickTeamInvitesListButton" and function calls the activity class where I am redirecting it to the fragment, so that I could access the list view.

The function in activity looks like this.

```
public void onClickTeamInvitesListButton(View view) {
        fragmentTeamInvites.onClickTeamInvitesListButton(view);
    }
```

Function in fragment is like this.

```
 private static ListView listView;
 private static MyListAdapter mListAdapter;
...
...
public void onClickDeleteButton(View view) {
        int position = listView.getPositionForView(view);
        listView.removeViewAt(position);
        mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Found the answer .. needed to change my list code to this.

```
public void onClickDeleteButton(View view) {
        int position = listView.getPositionForView(view);
        listDataModel.remove(position);
        mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
public void onClickDeleteButton(View view) {
    int position = listView.getPositionForView(view);
    listView.removeViewAt(position);
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You are removing the item from the `ListView`, not from the datasource (the adapter). So, when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` the adapter attempts to refresh the data, but since nothing has changed in the data, it displays all rows again.

You should **remove the item from your adapter**, not from the `ListView`!

Comment: Thank you for replying , but i tried that and i see no method to remove a single row from the list adapter. Do you have any suggestions ???

Comment: Removing the item from the adapter implies removing the item from the **data source** of the adapter (e.g. the ListArray that feeds the adapter)